# How can i assign a varaible in a variable

Tags: ansible

Here's my task.

```
- name: Add A record for "{{ ec2_hostname }}.{{ internal_domain }}"  
  route53:
      command: create
      zone: "{{ internal_domain }}"
      private_zone: "{{ private_type }}"
      record: "{{ ec2_hostname }}.{{ internal_domain }}"
      type: A
      ttl: 300
      value: "{{ ansible_ec2_[ec2_r53_type]_ipv4 }}"
```

Specifically having trouble with this line:

```
value: "{{ ansible_ec2_[ec2_r53_type]_ipv4 }}"
```

I need to insert `ec2_r53_type` inside a string to create another variable.  This should be either "public" or "local".

So the expected result should be

```
value: "{{ ansible_ec2_local_ipv4 }}"
```

or

```
value: "{{ ansible_ec2_public_ipv4 }}"
```

Whats the logic here, tried all i knew no luck

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
value: "{{ vars['ansible_ec2_' + ec2_r53_type + '_ipv4'] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 - find: ^CODEDEPLOY_USER=""
   replace: CODEDEPLOY_USER=""{{ app_install_user }}""
```

"/"{{ app_install_user }}/"" something as such, This is on the vars folder of a play

I would require to add the variable in qoutes on the vars of roles.
roles/xxxx/vars/main.yml

app_install_user is added on group_vars of ansible